# Does the new Airpod Max support lossless audio on wireless?

Tags: wifi, bluetooth, airpods, audio

Earlier AirPods and AirPods Pro models send audio over 256kbps AAC.

As I use Tidal HiFi (lossless streaming) and some offline flac/wav files, I still need to use wired headphones, and I need to get 3-4 lightning to 3.5mm jack adapters each year, as they go off often.

I'm thinking about buying the AirPods Max, but I won't buy it if it's still limited to the same 256kbps AAC recompression as the earlier AirPods.

It seems it uses Bluetooth 5.0 which by itself supports up to 2Mbps, also it may have it's own wireless chip again, so I see the chance, but I'm awaiting confirmation as Apple's marketing page didn't convince me if it's supported or not: https://www.apple.com/uk/airpods-max/

Question:
Does someone know if AirPods Max support lossless audio over wireless?

Comment: Side note: I applied gradually increasing diameters of heat-shrink tubing around a Lightning > 3.5mm adapter to make it more rugged. I've been using one daily for about 2 years and it has not broken. It becomes a solid, inflexible cylinder.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Do Bluetooth connections support lossless audio?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/422452/do-bluetooth-connections-support-lossless-audio)

Comment: This question is definitely related. When I asked this specific question I knew this is the case up AirPods Pro 2020. I asked this specific question when Apple announced the release of Airpods Max. The question was about an ambiguous line about high fidelity audio in Apple's release notes. Your question and your answer there describes the market and its limitations and how in the end of the day all bluetooth audio is lossy. But when I asked this question I was aware, and I wanted to know if anything changed, if there was an innovation for FLAC/ALAC/MQA+/Waw support over any wireless method.

Comment: A custom radio, or non-standard tech would be able to give you lossless wireless.  How small can they shrink a WiFi chip, and let iOS use a second channel?

Comment: AirPods (normal/Pro) is definitely not that size. I was curious as in case of AirPods Max it did not seem impossible to give a decent size battery and wireless chip for this. The main thing is they did not solve what I asked in this post back then. But I see a chance they will do in next few years, at least on the over-ear size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not. Apple's current implementation of the bluetooth 5.0 specification does not allow for support of any lossless codec. And in any case the real world  performance of the bluetooth chipset can not sustain 2 Mbps beyond very short ranges so you may as well use a long cable to connect it.

Comment: "Apple's current implementation of the bluetooth 5.0 specification does not allow for support of any lossless codec." - do you have any source to back this? Are we sure this didn't change in latest iOS 14.3 and macOS 11.1?

Comment: See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corebluetooth#overview and  https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/NetworkingInternetWeb/Conceptual/CoreBluetooth_concepts/AboutCoreBluetooth/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013257 and the relevant documents from the bluetooth SIG.

Answer (score 1):

There isn't any such thing as lossless Bluetooth for audio... Even Sony's LDAC is 900 Kbps. I'm listening to a 11.2 Mbps DSD Pink Floyd album as I type this on my Audeze wired headphones. With LDAC bluetooth, I'd lose 92% of the quality.

Comment: Not precisely 92% of the quality though. Information have importance and the most important ones are preserved according to the codec documentation.

Comment: Yes good point my friend...

Answer (score 0):

## Misconceptions

256 kbps AAC files are compressed by transcoding causing further information loss to AirPods when streaming from an Apple Device.

### The Reality

There is no 256 kbps AAC compression to AirPods.

### Some insights

The idea can easily be called "lossless" audio because AAC audio files are not transcoded and then decoded by various Bluetooth specifications; they are simply transmitted and decoded without the transcode step.

What lossless means in this sense is that the AAC file is delivered bit-for-bit to your AirPods. Any other format will first need to be transcoded on the fly to be shrunk down to the bandwidth limitations of arbitrary audio formats like mp3.

### Charts and references

You can see this in how bitrates are transcoded to constant or have encode-decode lag in transmission:
[image: Bluetooth Audio Transcoders]
*Transcoding a 256 kbps AAC file to a higher kbps file **will cause even more information to be lost** as transcoding is a lossy compression technique.*

For AAC, again, there is no encoding performed on the original audio, and thus the only decoding done is of the original audio stream.

More data dispelling false idea that AAC is transcoding from Apple device to Apple BT devices<sup>2</sup>:
[image: Reference: W Series Chips]

## See also

[About lossless audio in Apple Music](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT212183)

> While the difference between AAC and lossless audio is virtually indistinguishable, we’re offering Apple Music subscribers the option to access music in lossless audio compression.

> AirPods, AirPods Pro, AirPods Max, and Beats wireless headphones use Apple AAC Bluetooth Codec to ensure excellent audio quality. However, Bluetooth connections aren't lossless.

## References

Ref 1: [AptX Variants](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=AptX&oldid=1015959297#Variantsttps://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AptXs&oldid=101616456)

Ref 2: [Apple Designed Processors > W series](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Apple-designed_processors&oldid=1016164565#W_series)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/122958/discussion-between-nohillside-and-louis-waweru).

Comment: Important side notes to summarise: iOS does not support aptX (only macOS does). Apple Music 256k AAC is sent without re-encoding, but Tidal MQA+/flac and seem to be re-encoded to 256kbps AAC before being sent to AirPods (the question was asked to confirm if this happens, and I asked it right after the release announcement). Also Spotify Premium 320kbps ogg sounds seems to become audible on AirPods after two lossy compressions (first the ogg, then the aac). So the "no recompression" part only applies to AAC source files including Apple Music

Comment: Is Apple Music really sent without re-encoding? Any reference for this? How do other sounds like notifications get inserted if this is the case?

Comment: Yeah, when I was reading about the chips that keep the connection stable I also learned these chips or Apple devices just know not to transcode but send the full 256Kbps AAC file. I can find, feel free to look for yourself too.

Comment: Check out H1 H2 whatever extra custom designed semiconductor microprocessor they added in to improve Bluetooth terrible stability with anything moving

Comment: Remember only for Apple devices

Comment: eh this is the best I could find in the time left for this question. Please flag it as a dupe of the generalized question. https://www.nytimes.com/wirecutter/blog/what-you-need-to-know-about-bluetooth-audio/

Comment: Thanks! That's good to know. So no real benefit to using lossless with Bluethooth AAC headphones if I'm already using 256 AAC through Apple Music. It would just require more processing to encode them to 256 AAC before transmission.

Comment: I don’t know then behavior, we need toneee official docs. It might try harder or sound worse